# Magento Buy Now Button is not adding configurable products to cart

Tags: magento

please visit [link1](http://hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package/index.php/anashria-womens-premier-leather-sandal.html)

if we add product to cart through "Buy Now" button, than in cart page, we can see "

Both 1)Configurable Product 2)Simple Product.

but if we do same in this  [link2](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship.html) , than only simple product is displaying in cart page

template path hints for both sites :

[link3](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship.html?tp=1&code=toy)

[link4](http://hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package/index.php/anashria-womens-premier-leather-sandal.html?tp=1&code=toy)

we are using same code for "Buy Now" button and cart page.

I want to know where i am missing?

**Edit**

i am using this extension : https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

This is the problem. But i want to fix the issue by keeping this extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both link1 and link2 are configurable products and when we move product to there cart then in database an item entity will be created and added in cart .

please test again and use 
Mage::log($product,Zend_log::INFO,'layout.log',true);

to debug cartController.php

Comment: i replaced the default cartcontoller.php file, but still its not working.

Comment: i am using this extension : https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple this is the problem. if i disable the extension, its works fine, but how to solve the issue by keeping this extension